# Energy without temperature

Tags: thermodynamics, energy, statistical-mechanics

If you know the entropy $S$ of your system. Is there a general way to calculate the internal energy $U$ of your system?

So the entropy $S$ is the *only* thing I know of my system. I have no information about the temperature $T$, so I can't simply use the fact that $$S= \left.\frac{\partial U}{\partial T} \right|_V.$$

Will it be possible to tell something about my system, given that I only know it's entropy ?

Comment: In crude terms: entropy denotes the number of degrees of freedom that are activated, and the energy per active degree of freedom is the temperature. If you only know the number of degrees of freedom (and not their energy), it will not be feasible to derive any energy related parameters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, if $S$ is really the only thing you know about your system then there is no way to know its energy. There is no relationship between the energy and the entropy that doesn't involve some other quantity such as temperature.

...but surely you know *something* about your system, other than its entropy? I mean, you must know something about what it's made of, how big it is, and so on, otherwise you'd have no reason to be interested in it in the first place. Perhaps by taking some of that into account you might be able to say something useful, though of course this is highly dependent on your particular situation.

Comment: It's in a spin-system with an undefined temperature.

Comment: But nevertheless your answer is true! Just like in a classical gas we need at least 2 statevariables, so we need at least 2 for any other system.